# DynamoDB disable auto-scaling programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I want to run a daily update of a set of Dynamo tables. I have written a console app to do this however I want to be able to programmatically disable the capacity auto-scaling at the start of the update process and then re-enable it at the end.

I have managed to increase the provisioned throughput for both the table and it's Global Secondary Indexes using the [UpdateTableAsync](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/items/MDynamoDBv2IDynamoDBUpdateTableAsyncUpdateTableRequestCancellationTokenNET45.html) method but this does not have any options for handling auto-scaling and I can't find any other functionality to let me do this.

Does it even exist?

EDIT: I have found the CLI command required for this here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/application-autoscaling/delete-scaling-policy.html. My question is now, does this exist anywhere in the .NET SDK?

Comment: You are in luck. AWS added the functionality to suspend and resume autoscaling the other day. https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/08/suspend-resume-scaling-now-available-in-aws-application-auto-scaling/

Answer (score 4):

After a lot of digging through the AWS documentation (there doesn't seem to be any tutorials or examples, especially for .NET) I've discovered that this functionality does exist but it is not at Dynamo-level. It is an AWS-wide package that handles auto-scaling for all AWS resources.

There is a nuget package called `AWSSDK.ApplicationAutoScaling`. You'll need to create yourself an instance of `AmazonApplicationAutoScalingClient` (in the code below, this is represented by `autoScaling`).

When setting up auto-scaling in the AWS DynamoDB Console, two things are created; a description of the scaling (min capacity, max capacity etc) and a policy which I believe links the auto-scaling with CloudWatch so that alrms can be raised. Both of these objects need to be managed.

To solve my problem of disabling auto-scaling and then re-enabling it after updating my tables I had to following this process:

Save the policies and scaling descriptions (called `ScalableTargets`) before running the update.

```
this.preUpdatePolicies = (await autoScaling.DescribeScalingPoliciesAsync(new DescribeScalingPoliciesRequest
{
    ResourceId = $"table/{this.tableName}",
    ServiceNamespace = ServiceNamespace.Dynamodb,
    ScalableDimension = ScalableDimension.DynamodbTableWriteCapacityUnits
})).ScalingPolicies;

this.preUpdateScaling = (await autoScaling.DescribeScalableTargetsAsync(new DescribeScalableTargetsRequest
{
    ResourceIds = new List<string>() { $"table/{this.tableName}" },
    ServiceNamespace = ServiceNamespace.Dynamodb,
    ScalableDimension = ScalableDimension.DynamodbTableWriteCapacityUnits
})).ScalableTargets;
```

I then deregister the scaling descriptions which also deletes any associated policies.

```
foreach (var scaling in this.preUpdateScaling)
{
    await autoScaling.DeregisterScalableTargetAsync(new DeregisterScalableTargetRequest
    {
        ResourceId = scaling.ResourceId,
        ServiceNamespace = ServiceNamespace.Dynamodb,
        ScalableDimension = ScalableDimension.DynamodbTableWriteCapacityUnits
    });
}
```

After I have run my update I then reregister the descriptions/scalable targets and put the policies back based on the values I saved before running the update.

```
foreach (var scaling in this.preUpdateScaling)
{
    await autoScaling.RegisterScalableTargetAsync(new RegisterScalableTargetRequest
    {
        ResourceId = scaling.ResourceId,
        ServiceNamespace = scaling.ServiceNamespace,
        ScalableDimension = scaling.ScalableDimension,
        RoleARN = scaling.RoleARN,
        MinCapacity = scaling.MinCapacity,
        MaxCapacity = scaling.MaxCapacity
    });
}

foreach (var policy in this.preUpdatePolicies)
{
    await autoScaling.PutScalingPolicyAsync(new PutScalingPolicyRequest
    {
        ServiceNamespace = policy.ServiceNamespace,
        ResourceId = policy.ResourceId,
        ScalableDimension = policy.ScalableDimension,
        PolicyName = policy.PolicyName,
        PolicyType = policy.PolicyType,
        TargetTrackingScalingPolicyConfiguration = policy.TargetTrackingScalingPolicyConfiguration
    });
}
```

Hopefully this is helpful for anyone else who would like to use .NET to manage auto-scaling.